# Converting input XML to JSON format in WSO2 ESB

Tags: json, wso2-esb

I want to convert the input XML to JSON format in WSO2 ESB.
I have tried using  the property mediator but it is not working,

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
<property name="Content-Type" value="application/json" scope="transport" type="STRING"></property>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this configuration:

```
<inSequence>
...
</inSequence>
<outSequence>
  <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
  <respond/>
</outSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add formatter (which is define by messageType property) to format out going message.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
```

Content-Type property is used to build incoming message to the format of the SOAP, which is used inside the ESB. If incoming message is XML you can use the following builder. Adding this property is not compulsory, if the "Content-Type" is sent with the incoming message headers ESB automatically pic it and build the message.

```
<property name="Content-Type" value="application/xml" scope="transport" type="STRING"></property>
```

Also make sure you have enable the "application/json" message formatters inside the axis2.xml file. this can be found inside the repository/conf/axis2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your  xml input is,

```
 <name>abc</name>
<id>123</id>
```

Then you need to convert it to Json format as,

```
{ 
  "name" : "abc",
   "id" : "123"
}
```

You can use PayloadFactory mediator to convert XML to JSON format

```
 <payloadFactory media-type="json">
       <format>
           {
        "name" : "$1",
        "id" : "$2"
           }
       </format>
        <args>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//name"/>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//id"/>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
```

Hope this helps!!