# ERROR: Mapping failed Error while parsing XML input stream. Current context not Object but root

Tags: json, xml, wso2

I'm getting this error (specified in the title) while using DataMapper mediator in Wso2 Enterprise integrator. Following is my .dmc file

```
var outputroot={};

outputroot =  {};
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse =  {};
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult =  {};
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.Company = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.Company;
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.Valid = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.Valid;
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.Use = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.Use;
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.State = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.State;
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.OriginalNumber = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.OriginalNumber;
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.CleanNumber = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.CleanNumber;
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.Country = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.Country;
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.PrefixType = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.PrefixType;
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.sms = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.sms;
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.AssignDate = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.AssignDate;
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.TelecomState = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.TelecomState;
outputroot.CheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.Wireless = inputCheckPhoneNumberResponse.CheckPhoneNumberResult.Wireless;
outputroot.NewObject =  {};
return outputroot;
};
```

my sample input xml is given below

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <CheckPhoneNumberResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/PhoneVerify/query">
            <CheckPhoneNumberResult>
                <Company>Toll Free</Company>
                <Valid>true</Valid>
                <Use>Assigned to a code holder for normal use.</Use>
                <State>TF</State>
                <OriginalNumber>18006785432</OriginalNumber>
                <CleanNumber>8006785432</CleanNumber>
                <Country>United States</Country>
                <PrefixType>Landline</PrefixType>
                <sms>Landline</sms>
                <AssignDate>Unknown</AssignDate>
                <TelecomState>TF</TelecomState>
                <Wireless>false</Wireless>
            </CheckPhoneNumberResult>
        </CheckPhoneNumberResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My sample output Json is given below

```
{
  "CheckPhoneNumberResponse": {
    "CheckPhoneNumberResult": {
      "Company": "Toll Free",
      "Valid": true,
      "Use": "Assigned to a code holder for normal use.",
      "State": "TF",
      "OriginalNumber": 18006785432,
      "CleanNumber": 8006785432,
      "Country": "United States",
      "PrefixType": "Landline",
      "sms": "Landline",
      "AssignDate": "Unknown",
      "TelecomState": "TF",
      "Wireless": false
    }
  }
}
```

I'm unable to change the context for my input xml. can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

In your input XML, the `CheckPhoneNumberResponse` element uses a default [namespace](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) (without any prefix). As a result the data mapper will add a prefix called `axis2ns2` to the inputSchema file located in the data mapper config project(where your dmc file is located). To solve the issue, you can either remove this prefix from the inputSchema file so that the value of the namespace looks similar as below,

```json
  "namespaces" : [ {
    "url" : "http://ws.cdyne.com/PhoneVerify/query"
  } ]
```

Or if there is any possibility you may add a prefix to the `CheckPhoneNumberResponse` namespace.

btw, if you just want to convert the SOAP to a REST you can follow the below-mentioned approaches as well.

[Converting input XML to JSON format in WSO2 ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719089/converting-input-xml-to-json-format-in-wso2-esb)